# creating unique new column id by selecting first 7 characters from a column X and inserting into the new column Y for 10 000 records within same table

Tags: sql

I need to create a new column in the same table for unique IDs.

Here is an illustration:

Table X contains the following:

```
 2534334gt,
 7654398ty, 
 9476748ff,
 8454945po
```

New table X:

```
 2534334,
 7654398, 
 9476748,
 8454945
```

here is my current code which is giving errors:

```
declare @count int
declare @NewID VARCHAR(25)

select @count= MAX([dit_id]) FROM [dbase].[dbo].[X]

WHILE(@count > 0)
BEGIN
 /*IF EXISTS(SELECT LEFT([dit_id], 7)FROM [dbase].[dbo].[X] WHERE ID=@count)*/
 set @NewID = (SELECT LEFT([dit_id], 7)FROM [dbase].[dbo].[x] WHERE ID=@count)

BEGIN
 UPDATE [dbase].[dbo].[X]
  set[dbase].[dbo].[X].[TheNew_ID] = @NewID
  WHERE ID=@count
END

SET @count = @count - 1
END

SELECT * FROM [dbase].[dbo].[X] (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: If you get an error, please post it.

Comment: Your `BEGIN` before your `UPDATE` looks wrong.  A begin end is to encapsulate the code for a `while`, or `if`.  Pretty sure you need to move it up before your `SET`

Comment: What's your plan if you have values of 2534334gt and 2534334gg?  The numeric parts are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work as a set rather than row by row which should make it a bit faster

```
UPDATE [dbase].[dbo].[X]
set [dbase].[dbo].[X].[TheNew_ID] = LEFT([dbase].[dbo].[X].[dit_id], 7)
where id in (select id from [dbase].[dbo].[X] limit 10000);
```

Some databases should support limit in the update statement in which case you could write it as

```
UPDATE [dbase].[dbo].[X]
set [dbase].[dbo].[X].[TheNew_ID] = LEFT([dit_id], 7)
limit 10000;
```

Comment: +1 tho, if its a sql server platform, use `TOP` instead.